# updating values on 2D matrix after using indices and boolean selection

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix to store *k* minimum distances for N elements. Whenever a new element arrives I want to compute the distances to all N elements and if any distance is lower to the maximum distance stored I want to update that value and store the new distance. Initially the distances are set to `np.inf`.

```
elems = np.array([[5, 5],[4, 4],[8, 8]])
k=2
center_mindists = np.full((len(elems),k), np.inf)
```

So when a new element arrives, let's say `x=np.array([1,1])` I have to compute the distance to all elements and store it if it is lesser than the maximum distance stored at the time

```
distances = np.sum(np.abs(elems - x)) #[8 6 14]
```

To do so, I find the indices where there is the maximum distance in each row and then select the max stored distances that are higher to the recently computed distance

```
max_min_idx = np.argmax(center_mindists, axis=1) #[0 0 0]
id0 = np.indices(max_min_idx.shape)
lower_id = distances < centers_mindists[id0, max_min_idx]
```

Finally I have to update those values with the new ones:

```
center_mindists[id0, max_min_idx][lower_idx] = distances[lower_idx[0]]
```

The thing is that the assignation does not change the values on the `center_min_dists` matrix and I couldn't find a solution for this.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Are you trying to run K-nearest neighbours? You can vectorize this you know.

Comment: Index the index instead of the array. I think something along the lines of `center_mindists[id0[lower_idx], max_min_idx] = distances[lower_idx[0]]`. When you do it the other way, you inevitably have to make a temp copy to satisfy the fancy index, so the assigned data gets trashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform the assignment in two steps, since you have a double index, the first part of which makes a copy. Instead of

```
center_mindists[id0, max_min_idx][lower_idx] = distances[lower_idx[0]]
```

explicitly update the copy, and assign it back:

```
temp = center_mindists[id0, max_min_idx]
temp[lower_idx] = distances[lower_idx[0]]
center_mindists[id0, max_min_idx] = temp
```

This is actually pretty convenient because you really use `temp` to compute the `lower_idx` mask in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

`center_mindists[id0, max_min_idx]` is a copy, because the indices are not slices (basic indexing).

```
center_mindists[id0, max_min_idx][lower_idx] = ...
```

modifies that copy, not the original, so nothing ends up happening.

You have to somehow combine indices so that you have only one set of advanced indexing

```
center_mindists[idx0, idx1] = ....
```